# How to change background color and text of notifyIcon component

Tags: c#, notifyicon

How to change background color and text of notifyIcon component?

[image]

Comment: At least the Text is a simple property.

Comment: That's not a NotifyIcon, that's a balloon tip.  Displayed by Explorer, not your program.  The user is very familiar with what they look like already, no need for a hotdog-stand color scheme.  Well, not like you *could* change it if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the text, you want the [BalloonTipText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.balloontiptext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
var notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Your string here";
```

However the balloon's background color cannot be set using this type. If you really must change it, you can instead use the Shell_NotifyIcon function in the Win32API, as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2043/Displaying-a-Notify-Icon-s-Balloon-Tool-Tip).